# How to convert a list of Songs into stream of Strings?

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have a list of songs, which is a class with 3 values: `songName`, `albumName`, `duration` and `hash`.
I have written a function which returns a `Stream<String>` of all the songs ordered by name.
My first idea was this:

```
public Stream<String> orderedSongNames() {
     return songs.stream().sorted((s1,s2)>s1.getSongName().compareTo(s2.getSongName()));
}
```

The problem is that in this way, the return value is a `Stream<Song>` but i want a `Stream<String>`. does anyone have an idea of how i can solve the problem at hand?

Comment: you are missing a dash here `(s1,s2)->` (instead of `(s1,s2)>`). You may consider `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Song::getSongName))` instead

Comment: If you want  a "stream of Strings"  why do you have a problem with "return value is a Stream"? It's also not clear if you want a to return Songs or Strings. You got a bunch of answers in which each answerer understood your questions as he wanted, please clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you’ve overridden the `toString` method; you can return a stream of each objects String representation like so:

```
return songs.stream()
            .sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.getSongName().compareTo(s2.getSongName()))
            .map(Object::toString);
```

Or if you want to return a `Stream<String>` where the strings are the song names.

```
return songs.stream()
            .sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.getSongName().compareTo(s2.getSongName()))
            .map(Song::getSongName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a `Stream<String>` of song names sorted by length,
then first *map* the `Song` instances to `String` by getting their names.

```
public Stream<String> orderedSongNames() {
    return songs.stream()
        .map(Song::getSongName)
        .sorted(String::compareTo);
}
```

You could sort first and map after as some other answers suggest,
the result and the process is pretty much the same,
but a bit more verbose to write,
that's why I reordered these operations:

```
public Stream<String> orderedSongNames() {
    return songs.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Song::getSongName))
        .map(Song::getSongName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to map it:

```
public Stream<String> orderedSongNames() {
  return songs.stream()    
    .sorted((s1,s2)>s1.getSongName().compareTo(s2.getSongName()))
    .map((s) -> s.getSongName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the dash before `>`:

```
return songs.stream().sorted((s1,s2)->s1.getSongName().compareTo(s2.getSongName()));
                                    ^--- here
```

But instead, just do this:

```
return songs.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Song::getSongName));
```